# CSS: fixed header on div with scrollbar starting NEXT to the header

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a CSS-only solution, to create a fixed header on a div, where the scrollbar for the content starts next to (and not below of) the header. To get an idea on how it should look, have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4uL6/

Here, I tried to take the following approach:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="top">Title</div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content">
            .... Text Content here ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.top {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.body {
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that the content lies on top of the header (you'll see it as soon as you start scrolling). It however *feels* like, it is really close to a solution. But since I haven't found anything on the web, I fear that this is only doable with JavaScript. So is that true or is there a CSS-only solution for this problem?

Comment: was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/V4uL6/2/) what you were looking for?

Comment: @Amir5000 Thanks, but no. There is the same problem that I discussed with Hiigaran. You manually fit the header to the size of the scrollbar, which is not a reliable solution, since different browsers have different scrollbars. When I open your fiddle in chrome on ubuntu, I already see, that the header overlaps the scrollbar by a few pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! The trick is to apply `z-index: -1` to the `content` element and remove the `z-index` from all other elements:

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.top {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

.body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4uL6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index` on `body` to 1, or any number lower than the `z-index` on `top`.

EDIT: You still have the issue of the scrollbar being hidden, but since you said you wanted the scrollbar next to, and not under the header, you can change that by adjusting the width on the content classes.

Comment: yeah, I tried that before, but I don't see how I can then keep the header from overlaying the scrollbar. How could adjusting the width on the content help?

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure if there's a more elegant solution, but if you set the width of `body` to something higher than 100%, you'll move the scrollbar out enough to align it perfectly. However, this means that you need to make the `outer` width, along with every single parent width a percentage width as well (instead of pixels), because once the browser width, or screen size/resolution changes, you'll see something different, and the alignment will be lost. On the bright side, doing so will allow you to have a layout that will be seen exactly as it is for every possible user configuration.

Comment: ok, I think I get what you mean. The is problem is however, that I need to align it manually to the width of the scrollbar. And since different browsers have different scrollbars, this is not really a reliable solution. But thanks anyway, I'm more and more convinced, that it can't be done with only CSS.

Comment: Well don't give up too quickly. I'm far from the most experienced when it comes to CSS, so I'm sure someone would be able to come up with something else.